# Flyway: Unable to find path for sql migrations

Tags: flyway

While running flyway migrate I am getting following error:

***Unable to find path for sql migrations: /path to migration folder/***

I am trying to following command: 
**java -cp  com.googlecode.flyway.commandline.Main migrate**

I also added the migration folder in the classpath and specified the baseDir directory. But nothing seems to help. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you calling the java executable directly instead of using the supplied shell script?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is an [open bug](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/issues/detail?id=156).  I've submitted a question asking for workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134786/how-do-i-best-work-around-flyway-issue-156), but in the meantime please star the issue in the bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an alternative migrations framework, try Mite.  I've had good success with it.  It's Sql based so you don't have to learn a new framework and language agnostic because it's just a utility.

https://github.com/soitgoes/mite