# How do I best work around Flyway issue 156?

Tags: flyway

I'm trying to get Flyway configured and have run up against [issue 156](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/issues/detail?id=156), where I can't escape the following message:

```
[WARNING] Unable to find path for sql migrations: db/migration
```

The folder exists, contains an sql script named `V1__baseline.sql` and is relative to the path of both the `pom.xml` and the current working directory when invoking `mvn flyway:migrate`.

The relevant section of my `pom.xml` looks like this:

```xml
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <serverId>myServer</serverId>
                <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myProject</url>
                <table>schema_history</table>
                <baseDir>db/migration</baseDir>
                <basePackage>com.mycompany.myProject.migration</basePackage>
                <validationMode>ALL</validationMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This appears to be a known problem but there is remarkably little chatter about it given that the first report is from August 2011 and that it still exists in the current stable version (1.5).

You all must be working around it somehow.  What's the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue 156 only applies to OSGi environments.

**baseDir** refers to a **location on the classpath**.

In your case this would be: PROJECT_ROOT/src/main/resources/db/migration

Put your migrations there and it should work. I'll have another look at the docs to see if they can be clarified regarding this.

Comment: Ah yes, that worked.  And looking at the docs now, I can see that actually the [docs are correct](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/wiki/SqlMigration) and I just misread them.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry I'm having trouble with this exact thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020351/flyway-not-finding-my-sql-migrations-in-db-migration  I've read the docs, and can't quite figure out what's going on.