# Flyway not finding my sql migrations in db/migration

Tags: flyway

The error:
[ERROR] com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to determine URL for classpath location: db/migration (ClassLoader: ClassRealm[plugin>com.googlecode.flyway:flyway-maven-plugin:2.1.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@43be2d65])

I followed the quickstart, so I'm not really doing anything complex yet.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.cpt.migrations</groupId>
  <artifactId>cpt_migrations</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>cpt_migrations</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.24</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
              <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.1.1</version>
              <configuration>
                  <user>root</user>
                  <password></password>
                  <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                  <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cpt</url>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And my folder structure is the prescribed PROJECT_ROOT/src/main/resources/db/migration/V1__Base_version.sql:

I get the error when, from the PROJECT_ROOT, I execute:
mvn flyway:migrate

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't forget to call compile first, to make sure the resources are copied over.

Comment: what do you mean? can you explain better?
I used netbeans 7.4

Comment: @Axel Fontaine like Jeff I have configured my pom.xml and I have my .sql scripts in the db/migration folder under resources.. on execution of the compile flyway:migrate I get com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to create schema ``: Incorrect database name '' what could be the issue? my sql file name is test.sql

Comment: What if I have my sql files in the current folder and not in db/migration? how to solve the problem? I do compile and then call migrate too.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had to explicitely set

```
flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
```

in my application.properties (Spring Boot) for it to work.

Comment: Set where? Don't assume everyone is an expert in these things!

Comment: @Willa in the application.properties file of Spring Boot. I update the answer

Answer (score 3):

in my case this error was caused as package with name `db.migration` was created
instead of `db` -> `migration`

Answer (score 1):

In my case IntelliJ Idea created a folder `db.migration` instead of two separate folders `db` and `migration` inside

Answer (score 0):

It has to be compiled:

```
mvn compile flyway:migrate
```

You may use

```
<executions>
          <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>migrate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
```

in

```
<plugin>..</plugin>
```

and then just mvn compile is needed for execution of migrate task

Comment: I don't think executing migrations on compile is a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Execute mvn command from directory where target dir is located.