# Flyway 'migrate' ant task error: "Unable to find path for sql migrations [...]"

Tags: java, ant, classpath, flyway

I can not specify the correct path to the directory with .sql files. I tried to set the "baseDir" attribute to different directories in different places (in classpath, of course) and set different classpath. Build scripts always falls with message “**Unable to find path for sql migrations: [uri to directory with . sql files]**”.

It's not looking like [issue 156](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/issues/detail?id=156) as was said in [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811506/flyway-unable-to-find-path-for-sql-migrations), becourse if I delete the code in SqlMigrationResolver.java

```
if (StringUtils.hasText(baseDir) && !new ClassPathResource(baseDir + "/",
    classLoader).exists()) {
  LOG.warn("Unable to find path for sql migrations: " + baseDir);
  return migrations;
}
```

as was said in [Comment #9](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/issues/detail?id=156#c9) I still catch

```
deployDB:
[flyway:migrate] com.googlecode.flyway.core.exception.FlywayException: Error loading sql migration files
[flyway:migrate] Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [db/migration/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

BUILD FAILED
c:\DeployTest\build.xml:208: Flyway Error: com.googlecode.flyway.core.exception.FlywayException: Error loading sql migration files
```

Flyway falls at

```
resources = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(classLoader)
        .getResources("classpath:" + searchRoot + searchPattern);
```

It can not execute getResources method.

It's not looking like bug, it's looking like I can not set right uri to directory with my SQL scripts =(

Please, help me to set this damn uri!

My build.xml:

```
<target name="init-flyway">
  <taskdef uri="antlib:com.googlecode.flyway.ant"
           resource="com/googlecode/flyway/ant/antlib.xml"
  />
  <property name="flyway.driver" value="${dbDriver}"/>
  <property name="flyway.url" value="${dbUrl}"/>
  <property name="flyway.user" value="${dbScheme}"/>
  <property name="flyway.password" value="${dbPass}"/>
  <property name="flyway.baseDir" value="\db\migration"/>
  <property name="flyway.classpath" value="c:\DeployTest"/>
</target>

<target name="deployDB" depends="init-flyway">
  <flyway:migrate/>
</target>
```

Comment: Just to be sure, try by replacing your '\' by '/'.

Comment: @nico_ekito Yes, I have already tried to do that. It gave no results.

Comment: You tried "/db/migration" (from the error message, the first "/" is missing) ?

Comment: @nico_ekito Who I understand, it's doesn't matter, what kind of separator we use. I tried **"/db/migration"**, **"\db\migration"**, **"db/migration"** and **"db\migration"**. The error message was always **[db/migration/]**.

Comment: Does the "\db\migration" folder is a part of your ressources (ie is in the classpath) ?

Comment: @nico_ekito I'm confused =| I think, that property **"flyway.classpath"** set classpath, but it does not. I set classpath as attribute of migrate task (**<flyway:migrate classpath="c:\DeployTest"/>**) and this was a solution of my problem! Nico_ekito, thank you for your help =) !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing **flyway.classpath** from a *property* to a *path*.

For your case this means changing this:

```
<property name="flyway.classpath" value="c:\DeployTest"/>
```

to this:

```
<path id="flyway.classpath">
    <fileset dir="c:\DeployTest"/>
</path>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work in my case. I get too many exception like **Unable to obtain resource from {some file}: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
[flyway:migrate] Unable to obtain resource from {some file}:
[flyway:migrate] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file** I get these exceptions with all files in my directory.

Comment: As I said before, setting classpath as attribute of migrate task helped for me (**<flyway:migrate classpath="c:\DeployTest"/>**).

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue for me.  Though I am using the Maven Plugin, so adding the following to flyway's configuration element did the trick: `<classpath>${basedir}</classpath>`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
<path id="flyway.classpath"> 
    <fileset dir="c:\DeployTest"/> 
</path>
```

Use:

```
<path id="flyway.classpath">  
      <pathelement location="c:\DeployTest"/>
</path>
```